# Customizing Weekday/Workday Function to reflect actual working hours

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

So my company services clients with insurance products and we have two teams: Liability and Crime. There are generally one 4 different types of task: Binding, Issuance, Quoting and Rapids.

I currently have made a spreadsheet based on data obtained through our workflow. 
The main formulas I use to calculate service due date for Crime/Liability team is:
`=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(IF(A2="Binding",C2+(1/8),IF(A2="Quoting",C2+(1/8),IF(A2="Issuance",C2+2,IF(A2="Rapids",C2+(1/8),"")))))=1,WEEKDAY(IF(A2="Binding",C2+(1/8),IF(A2="Quoting",C2+(1/8),IF(A2="Issuance",C2+2,IF(A2="Rapids",C2+(1/8),"")))))=7,IF(A2="Binding",C2+(1/8),IF(A2="Quoting",C2+(1/8),IF(A2="Issuance",C2+2,IF(A2="Rapids",C2+(1/8),"")))))+2,IF(A2="Binding",C2+(1/8),IF(A2="Quoting",C2+(1/8),IF(A2="Issuance",C2+2,IF(A2="Rapids",C2+(1/8),"")))))`

Where you have 3 hours to finish binding, quoting, rapids, and you have two days for issuance.

We are now expanding our service to California, which is three hours behind EST time, so now comes the issue: We want to expand our working hours (est time) to 9 am - 8 pm to cover west coast. But, does is it possible to tell excel to do that via a weekday/workday function? 
The goal is to have the due dates wrap around weekends to Monday and anything after 8 pm (est time) to being due next day.

For example: If a binding task comes in at 7:00 pm, then you would have 1 hour till 8 pm, and so the task would be due at 11:00 am the next day. Is this even possible to do with just excel? Any help would be immensely appreciated guys, thank you!

Comment: I don’t have data to test this on, but a quick look seems to suggest that many of the if() statements can be reduced to =if(A2=“Issuance”,C2+2,C2+(1/8)). Note the quotes shown are not the ones to use so don’t copy/paste...

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to calculate the "time due", which would be 3 hours later (48 hrs later for issuance), only counting hours between 9am and 8pm Mon-Fri ?

Comment: yes @ashleedawg that's exactly what it is. I just haven't been able to get the due time wrap to wrap around to the next day, or if it's Friday then to Monday.

Comment: oh @SolarMike are you saying that parts of the formula that I have is redundant?

Comment: @roberth just look at how many times you repeat the same tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula can be simplified greatly if you have a lookup table in your workbook somewhere that returns the due time values. For the example below, my lookup table is in Sheet2, A1:

**Sheet 1 - Example Data**

```
    |   A    |  ...   |         C       |       D        |
    +--------+  ...   +-----------------+----------------+
1   |  Task  |        |   Received      | Due            |
2   |Binding |        |19/02/2018 09:00 |19/02/2018 12:00|
3   |Quoting |        |19/02/2018 13:00 |19/02/2018 15:00|
```

**Sheet 2 - Lookup table:**

```
    |   A    |   B   |
    +--------+-------+
1   |Binding | 0.125 |
2   |Quoting | 0.125 |
3   |Issuance| 2     |
4   |Rapids  | 0.125 |
```

**Formula**

The formula in Sheet1 D2 is:

```
=C2+INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

From there it should be a lot simpler to construct an `IF STATEMENT` to rollover to the next day if the order is received past 5pm (would be due after 8pm).

Comment: I thought about using a reference table initially too, but due to my lack of expertise, I couldn't find a way to construct it in a way in which it would wrap around weekends, holidays (I have a reference table for that) and outside of 9-8pm working hours @girlvsdata. Any suggestions on how to do that via using lookup table?

Comment: Also, how did you format the add-on time in sheet 2 - lookup table? Would formatting as number work? or is there a better one in custom tab?

Comment: Have you tried using my formula in your workbook? That should answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: I did, made a lookup table based on yours. Just changed time to "hh:mm" format for times. I will keep looking for ways to find the times wrap around weekends and holidays taking into account only working hours or 9-8 pm. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries, please upvote and/or choose my answer if it helped you. If you get stuck on adding the conditionals (wraparound for weekends) you would be better off making a new question out of this simplified code, since it would be much easier to provide as a [mcve].